# Reading CSV file using matlab- separating strings

Tags: matlab, csv, textscan

I am trying to read a CSV file using Matlab and plot it. Basically, I would like to plot time vs. heart rate. However, when I use `textscan` it copies both columns into one and I'm not sure how to separate it. I would like to save time in a variable `x` and heart rate in a variable `y` and plot them.

I have done this so far:

```
clear, clc;
ftoread = 'data.csv';
fid = fopen(ftoread); %Reads the CSV file
data = textscan(fid,'%s%f'); % Read in a string and a double
fclose(fid); % close
for i=2:size(data{1,1},1)% checks for size of the csv file
    x = strnum(data);%i need to separate the time from BPM using the comma thing and string command
    %y = data{2};
end
plot(x,y);
```

in the `data` cell in Matlab this is what I see:

```
'Time,BPM(HeartRate)'
'5:55:26,0'
'5:55:26,66'
'5:55:27,69'
'5:55:27,71'
'5:55:27,72'
```

etc.

In the `for` loop I would like to separate the time and save it in one variable and set heart rate to a different variable.

Comment: why not put the entire format in text scan '%d:%d:%d,%f' ?

Comment: @vish: One reason might be because then it's harder to use functions like [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) and [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), for example.

Comment: @horchler, i see what you mean, but datenum can receive datenum(2013,12,12,H,M,S) with H,M,S vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your basic question of how to read in the time values to one variable, and the readings into a second variable, use this:

```
clear;
clc;
ftoread = 'hr.csv';
fid = fopen(ftoread); %OPENS the CSV file
data = textscan(fid,'%s%f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',','); %Reads the file
fclose(fid); % closes the file

x = datenum(data{1}); %Time variables moved to new variable called x
y = data{2}; % Readings moved to variable y

plot(x,y); % plot bp readings vs time

% Create xlabel
xlabel('Time of Reading');

% Create ylabel
ylabel('Blood Pressure Reading');

% Create title
title('Blood Pressure Readings vs Time');
```

Your data currently does not look like much since the blood pressure readings are essentially all recorded at the same second.

To adjust your x-values so they are relative to the first reading and not the beginning of time, you can do this assuming csv entries come in order:

```
clear, clc;
ftoread = 'hr.csv';
fid = fopen(ftoread); %Reads the CSV file
data = textscan(fid,'%s%f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid); % close

x = datenum(data{1});
x = x - x(1); % Times relative to the first recorded time entry
y = data{2};

plot(x,y);

% Create xlabel
xlabel('Seconds since first reading');

% Create ylabel
ylabel('Blood Pressure Reading');

% Create title
title('Blood Pressure Readings vs Time');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the header information `'Time,BPM(HeartRate)'`? [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) has many nice features (see the documentation). In particular, you ask it to ignore a fixed number of header lines and you can tell it what delimiter to use (the default is whitespace):

```
data = textscan(fid,'%s%f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');
```

Now the output of `data{1}` will look like:

```
'5:55:26'
'5:55:26'
'5:55:27'
'5:55:27'
'5:55:27'
```

and `data{2}` will be a vector of double values.